# Multiple LEFT JOIN in SQL Running Slow. How do I optimize it?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I am combining three tables - persons, properties, totals - using `LEFT JOIN`.  I find the following query to be really fast but it does not give me all rows from table-1 for which there is no corresponding data in table-2 or table-3.  Basically, it gives me only rows where there is data in table-2 and table-3.

```
SELECT a.*, b.propery_address, c.person_asset_total
FROM persons AS a
LEFT JOIN properties AS b ON a.id = b.person_id
LEFT JOIN totals AS c ON a.id = c.person_id
WHERE a.city = 'New York' AND
      c.description = 'Total Immovable'
```

Whereas the following query gives me the correct result by including all rows from table-1 irrespective of whether there is corresponding data or no data from table-2 and table-3.  However, this query is taking a really long processing time.

```
FROM persons AS a
LEFT JOIN 
    properties AS b ON a.id = b.person_id
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT person_id, person_asset_total
     FROM totals
     WHERE description = 'Total Immovable'
    ) AS c ON a.id = c.person_id
WHERE a.city = 'New York'
```

Is there a better way to write a query that will give data equivalent to second query but with speed of execution equivalent to the first query?

Comment: In the first query, the WHERE clause disallows NULL values for `c.description`, and that negates the outerness of the left join, making it equivalent to an inner join. Relocate the `c.description = 'Total Immovable'` predicate from the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause of the LEFT JOIN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use a subquery:

```
SELECT p.*, pr.propery_address, t.person_asset_total
FROM persons p LEFT JOIN 
     properties pr
     ON p.id = pr.person_id LEFT JOIN 
     totals t
     ON a.id = c.person_id AND t.description = 'Total Immovable'
WHERE p.city = 'New York';
```

Your approach would be fine in almost any other database.  However, MySQL materializes "derived tables", which makes them much harder to optimize.  The above has the same effect.

You will also notice that I changed the table aliases to be abbreviations for the table names.  This makes the query much easier to follow.

Comment: Thank you @gordon ! The query works perfectly.  I read the contents of your book that you've mentioned on your profile.  Looks interesting to grasp some data mining concepts.

Comment: Just to add my two cent explanation to this wonderful solution:  including the WHERE clause about 'Total Immovable' at the end of the query, as the OP had done in the first query, applies the restriction AFTER the tables are joined.  So it will remove any rows which don't match, even though the JOIN is a left join.  Gordon's response applies the WHERE clause BEFORE the tables are joined.